# How can I reuse a Controller of a module in ZF2?

Tags: class, frameworks, module, controller, zend-framework2

Hello I am trying to instantiate a class controller of another class controller of a different module (created by me) that I am using but I can't do it because I get the message:

> Class 'ZfCommons\Controller\MyAbstractActionController' not found in
>   .....

and it is when I execute the command `use ZfCommons\Controller\MyAbstractActionController;`

The file that contents the class `MyAbstractActionController` the first command is:

```
namespace ZfCommons\Controller;
```

I guess I would have to do a require or include in PHP,but working with ZF2 I think maybe there is a more elegant way to do that.

How can I do it? Maybe I am using something wrong.
If you need to view more code I can copy and paste.

Comment: You must not use ZF Commons prefix as your module is not part of it.

Comment: Prefix for Zend Framework Commons is Zfc not ZfCommons so it's just misleading. As long as he does not publish it I think this is not much of a problem.

Comment: ok,thanks,I don't care how is the name,I can changed,but it does not solve the problem..I used ZfCommons like a module to extend the ZF2 classes,I think the name is not important

Comment: It is not important. I think it's common to name such a module StdLib through. Did my answer below help you? Did it not? If not what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get some service like object (e.g. some AuthService) you may register it as a service (you may have already done since you call `getAuthService()` on the controller) and use the ServiceLocator to get it or - even better for unit testing - inject it via a factory to your controller. You may want to take a look at [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) to see how it's done.

If you - for some reason - insist on using this hard-coded approach (which is really working against the framework) I think you just setup autoloading incorrectly or the ZfCommons module is not activated.

**First**

Check your application.config.php for activated modules. ZfCommons and Application need to be activated at least.

**Second**

Check ZfCommons' Module.php for initializing of the autoloader:

```
<?php
namespace ZfCommons;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface,
{
    // snip

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    // snip
}
```

This will initialize class autoloading for the namespace ZfCommons.

If your filenames map correctly to classes and interfaces according to [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) it should work now.